# Color Histogram based Image Search

Tags: java, image-processing, histogram, jai

I need to compare images on the basis of color histogram in java. I have Histogram of images which I did using JAI of java.

But I don't know how can i compare them using histogram.

Comment: In which way do you want to compare them, what is your expected result? Do you want to tell which is brighter? Which is bluer? Or which is nicer? You have to tell us more to get an answer.

Comment: thanks for you replay...
I just want to know how closely they match. like if I use image of apple with red color and round shape etc than i should have resultant images which may have red apple etc @user714965

Answer (score 2):

There are different methods for measuring similarity of histgorams.  One such method is Bhattacharya coefficient method.

You can use the following code for calculating this similarity measure:

```
float similarity = 0;
float[] targetHistogramData = ...//histogram1.getData();
float[] targetCandidateHistogramData = ...//histogram2.getData();

if( targetHistogramData.length != targetCandidateHistogramData.length){
    throw new IncompatibleHistogramsException();
}

for(int i = 0; i < targetHistogramData.length; i++){
    similarity += Math.sqrt(targetHistogramData[i]*targetCandidateHistogramData[i]);
}

return similarity;
```